# Can you cast the Conjure Elemental spell to summon an elemental within the area of effect of the Forbiddance spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning, area-of-effect

The [*forbiddance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance) spell description states:

> You create a ward against magical travel that protects up to 40,000 square feet of floor space to a height of 30 feet above the floor. For the duration, creatures can't teleport into the area or use portals [...] to enter the area. The spell also proofs the area against planar travel, and therefore prevents creatures from accessing the area by way of the Astral Plane, Ethereal Plane, Feywild, Shadowfell, or the *plane shift* spell.
>
> In addition, the spell damages types of creature that you choose when you cast it. Choose one or more of the following - celestials, elementals, fey, fiends, and undead. When a chosen creature enters the spell's area or starts its turn there, the creature takes 5d10 radiant or necrotic damage (your choice when you cast this spell). [...]

Can you cast the *conjure elemental* spell to summon an elemental within the area of effect of the *forbiddance* spell?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Have you taken the [tour]? This is good first question, I edited the phrasing to make the question title and body content match. If this no longer matches the intent of your question you can [edit] the question to make it clearer. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, *conjure elemental* will work

Nowhere in the description of [*conjure elemental*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-elemental) is it described as summoning the creature from another plane:

> You call forth an elemental servant. Choose an area of air, earth, fire or water that fills a 10-foot cube within range. An elemental of challenge rating 5 or lower appropriate to the area you chose appears in an unoccupied space with 10 feet of it. For example, a fire elemental emerges from a bonfire, and an earth elemental rises up from the ground.

From the description of the spell we can see that you are calling the elemental out of the existing environment. Not summoning it from another plane. Therefore *forbiddance* does not prevent it.

However...

#### It will still take damage

If the caster of *forbiddance* selects the elemental creature type, your conjured creature will take the damage when it is summoned and again at the start of each of its turns so long as it is within the area of *forbiddance*. You should keep this in mind when choosing which creature types to ward the area against.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use [Planar Ally] instead of [Conjure Elemental] in this situation?

Comment: Is this answer suggesting that a fire elemental happens to lurk in every fire / flame on the material plane?

Comment: @SeriousBri you could take it that way. That's somewhat how the spell is worded but I actually meant that you call out the elemental energy and conjure it into an elemental. Also the fire needs to be at least a 10 foot cube, so pretty massive fire

Answer (score 7):

## **No, conjure elemental will NOT work.**

From Monster Manual page 123:

> "Conjured by Magic. Certain spells and magic items can conjure an
> elemental, summoning it from the Inner Planes to the Material Plane."

The Ethereal Plane is a border between the Material Plane and the Inner Planes.

The forbiddance spell description states:

> "The spell also proofs the area against planar travel, and therefore
> prevents creatures from accessing the area by way of the Astral Plane,
> Ethereal Plane..."

Since you have no access to the Ethereal Plane therefor you have no access to the Inner Planes and you cannot conjure elemental.

It doesn't matter that the spell description doesn't specify it.
It is specified in the description of "elementals", MM p.123, specifying what is an "elemental".